# Magento 2 for cronjob

Tags: magento2, cron

This may sound like a dumb question but I really don't understand it. For example, [Magento 2 has been saying](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#config-cli-cron-bkg) to make sure "Magento cron job is running".

> **Create the cron job**
>   To create a cron job as the Magento file system owner, enter the following command as a user with root privileges:
>   `crontab -u <Magento file system owner user name> -e`
>   Then write in the file:
>   `"path-to-binary" -c "ini-file-path" "your Magento install dir"/bin/magento cron:run [>> "log-file"&]`
>   `"path-to-binary" -c "ini-file-path" "your Magento install dir"/update/cron.php [>> <log-file>&]`
>   `<path-to-binary> -c "ini-file-path" "your Magento install dir"/bin/magento setup:cron:run [>> "log-file"&]*`

As I said before, this was an example because my problem is that I do not know where to write those **commands**. It always says to write this command or write the other, but I can't find where I am supposed to put them.

**UPDATE:**
I have access to cPanel to manage my server and use FTP to upload the files.

Comment: Did you install Magento2 on a local machine or a server? Did you install it on Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: Magento 2 on server and I have a Windows laptop.

Comment: How are you connecting to your server? What connection possibilities do you have? FTP? SFTP? SSH? or maybe only via some admin panel (cPanel, DirectAdmin, Plesk)?

Comment: I have access with the cPanel and FTP, but mainly for files I use FTP.

Comment: Hi @Mirimari, were you able to solve this issue? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

There is no place to "put" the crontab. You run the `crontab` command as `root` and cron starts running. You don't have to change to a directory but you do have to create cron as the correct user.

[More info about cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

Comment: But how would I run the **"crontab command as root"**? Does this mean I write those commands in the file cron.php?

Comment: The answer to this question is, you log in as or elevate to root using `sudo` and enter the command. If you do not have `root` access, see the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

On a server you would enter those in the `crontab` command line tool via `crontab -e` but since you're using Windows please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20104043/387136).
It describes how you create a task in Windows `Task Scheduler`.

Optionally to test the cron you can also call `cron.php` from your browser

Answer (score 1):

The Magento2 documentation is describing how to set up cronjobs on a Linux machine when you have access to a terminal and can type these commands on a command line.

In your case, this is not possible. You have to set the cronjobs via your cPanel. I'm sure cPanel provides manuals/tutorials for that (I Googled and found [this](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs)).

See also [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/8012/3326) concerning cPanel and [magento-1.7](/questions/tagged/magento-1.7) cronjob.

There's some placeholders in the part of the documentation that you have quoted and the documentation explains what you need to put there. Of course you cannot enter the commands written there to find your PHP binary or your php.ini, so you need to [Google some more](https://www.google.com/#q=cpanel+%22php.ini%22) to find out where they are on your server.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote as it is exactly the right answer to the OP's question who is using cPanel to manage his website/webserver.

Comment: some things will never undrestand to anyone :)